# Text typing animation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

How to create text typing and deletion animation using css or bootstrap?

I have three header which should show one after one. 
First it should show typing of first header then erasing of first header, then typing of second header and then erasing of second header. It should keep on doing this.

Comment: There are multiple libraries for this. Have you searched for them?

Comment: Till now I have found only for one header and it's not getting erased

Comment: Use typed.js http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple js/jQuery string manipulation to simulate *write* and *erase* functions

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // take origin text
  var text = $('#content').text();
  // make content empty
  $('#content').text('');

  write(text);
});

function write(text) {
  var currentLetter = 0;
  var timer;

  //add letter by letter
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#content').append(text[currentLetter]);

    // if it's end of text, call erase function.
    if (currentLetter == text.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setTimeout(function() {erase(text);}, 1000);
    }

    currentLetter++;
  }, 2);
}

function erase(text) {
  var timer = '';
  var currentLetter = text.length - 1;

  // remove one letter from the end of text
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#content').text(text.substring(0, currentLetter));

    // if no more text - write text back;
    if (currentLetter == 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setTimeout(function() {write(text);}, 1000);
    }

    currentLetter--;
  }, 2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mauris arcu, auctor nec dui ut, accumsan imperdiet sapien. Cras eu varius dolor. Quisque tempus dapibus mattis. Donec tempus eleifend iaculis. Vivamus suscipit dui eu finibus consectetur. Curabitur dapibus ut mi quis vehicula. Vivamus vehicula lectus metus. In ex leo, fermentum sit amet laoreet at, tempus at urna. Quisque et ligula eget arcu convallis consectetur vel venenatis neque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce mollis risus in commodo bibendum. Donec lorem diam, auctor vel lectus vel, hendrerit semper nibh.</span>
```

Comment: How can I add multiple text or header here?

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper Move selectors to different global variables, apply on classes and so on

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this might help, I am trying to get the lines of text to all have a transparent background.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="typing-animation-container">
        <h2 style="background-color: rgba(252, 156, 249, 0)">
          As Your Trusted IT Partner,
        </h2>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mt-1">
          <div class="typed-strings">
            <div class="typed">&nbsp;</div>

            <h3 style="background-color: rgba(252, 156, 249, 0)">
              This is a test
            </h3>

            <p>
              we maintain your existing systems for mission-critical success
            </p>

            <p>we enhance your systems to meet required efficiencies</p>

            <p>we develop new systems to meet continuing demand</p>

            <p>we predict what systems you will need in the future</p>
          </div>

          <div class="typed">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28453157)

Answer (score 0):

After refining the above code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // take origin text
  var text = $('#content').text();
  // make content empty
  $('#content').text('');

  write(text);
});

function write(text) {
  var currentLetter = 0;
  var timer;

  //add letter by letter
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#content').append(text[currentLetter]);

    // if it's end of text, call erase function.
    if (currentLetter == text.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setTimeout(function() {erase(text);}, 1000);
    }

    currentLetter++;
  }, 20);
}

function erase(text) {
  var timer = '';
  var currentLetter = text.length - 1;

  // remove one letter from the end of text
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#content').text(text.substring(0, currentLetter));

    // if no more text - write text back;
    if (currentLetter == 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setTimeout(function() {write(text);}, 1000);
    }

    currentLetter--;
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mauris arcu, auctor nec dui ut, accumsan imperdiet sapien. Cras eu varius dolor. Quisque tempus dapibus mattis. Donec tempus eleifend iaculis. Vivamus suscipit dui eu finibus consectetur. Curabitur dapibus ut mi quis vehicula. Vivamus vehicula lectus metus. In ex leo, fermentum sit amet laoreet at, tempus at urna. Quisque et ligula eget arcu convallis consectetur vel venenatis neque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce mollis risus in commodo bibendum. Donec lorem diam, auctor vel lectus vel, hendrerit semper nibh.</span>|
```